# How to Change ADS password at initial login

Tags: c#, asp.net, ads

I want to change the initially assigned password at the next login on a ADS container..
How to do this programmatically ?

Comment: What do you mean by ADS container? Are you talking about Active Directory? How can a container have a password that you want to change?? Not very clear.... please rephrase and make it clearer!

Comment: Yes, I am refering to Active Directory Services. Container usually reffers to a Directory Entry within ADS

Answer (score 0):

You can change a password in Active Directory using the [DirectoryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx) class:

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ADPath, ADUser, ADPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
directoryEntry.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[]{strOldPassword, strNewPassword});
```

- [Resetting Passwords in Active Directory with C# ASP .NET](http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article66.aspx)